# Python 3 NoneType is Not Subscriptable Error

Tags: python

I am having a serious issue with this error. This is homework, so I am just looking for some hints on this... I've looked at the other questions, but they are not helping, so hopefully this is okay. I am new to Python. :) I am doing a Tic Tac Toe game. I am sure it has some other issues, but my main concern right now is this error. Here is my code:::

```
    scoreList = []
"""keeps track of all of the scores, moves, and indexes as tuples for each
        winning board"""

def getEmptySpaces(gameBoard):
    return gameBoard.count('-')

def winner(gameBoard):
    case1 = gameBoard[0]+gameBoard[1]+gameBoard[2]
    case2 = gameBoard[0]+gameBoard[3]+gameBoard[6]
    case3 = gameBoard[0]+gameBoard[4]+gameBoard[8]
    case4 = gameBoard[1]+gameBoard[4]+gameBoard[7]
    case5 = gameBoard[2]+gameBoard[5]+gameBoard[8]
    case6 = gameBoard[2]+gameBoard[4]+gameBoard[6]
    case7 = gameBoard[3]+gameBoard[4]+gameBoard[5]
    case8 = gameBoard[6]+gameBoard[7]+gameBoard[8]

    if case1 == 'xxx' or case1 == 'ooo':
        return True
    elif case2 == 'xxx' or case2 == 'ooo':
        return True
    elif case3 == 'xxx' or case3 == 'ooo':
        return True
    elif case4 == 'xxx' or case4 == 'ooo':
        return True
    elif case5 == 'xxx' or case5 == 'ooo':
        return True
    elif case6 == 'xxx' or case6 == 'ooo':
        return True
    elif case7 == 'xxx' or case7 =='ooo':
        return True
    elif case8 == 'xxx' or case8 == 'ooo':
        return True
    else:
        return False

def draw(gameBoard):
    if getEmptySpaces(gameBoard) ==0:
        if not winner(gameBoard):
            return True
        return False
    return False

def markX(gameBoard,index):
    gameBoard = gameBoard[:index] + 'x' + gameBoard[index+1:]

def markO(gameBoard,index):
    gameBoard = gameBoard[:index] + 'o' + gameBoard[index+1:]

def fitnessFunction(gameBoard):
    #only runs if end game or if all full
    if draw(gameBoard):
        return 0
    else:
        emptySpaces = getEmptySpaces(gameBoard)
        if emptySpaces %2 == 0:
            #max won
            return (emptySpaces + 1) *1
        else:
            #max lost
            return (emptySpaces + 1) *-1

def maxTurn(gameBoard):
    if getEmptySpaces(gameBoard) %2 == 0:
        return True
    return False

def minTurn(gameBoard):
    if getEmptySpaces(gameBoard) %2 != 0:
        return True
    return False

def miniMax(gameBoard):
    if winner(gameBoard) or getEmptySpaces(gameBoard) ==0:
        return fitnessFunction(gameBoard)
    else:
        emptyIndexes = [] 
        count = 0
        for char in str(gameBoard):
            if char == "-":
                emptyIndexes.append(count)
            count +=1             
        for index in emptyIndexes:
            xChild = markX(gameBoard,index)
            output = miniMax(xChild) #returns score
            scoreList.append((output,'x',index))

            oChild = markO(gameBoard,index)
            output = miniMax(oChild) #returns score
            scoreList.append((output,'o',index))
    return scoreList

def main():
    validChars = ['x','o','-']
    valid = True
    gameBoard = input("Please enter your current board configuration: ")

    for char in gameBoard:
        if char not in validChars:
            valid = False
    while not valid or len(gameBoard) !=9:
        print("Boards is not valid.")
        gameBoard = input("Please enter your current board configuarion: ")
        for char in gameBoard:
            valid = True
            if char not in validChars:
                valid = False

    else:
        listOfScores = miniMax(gameBoard)

        if maxTurn(gameBoard):
            best = max(listOfScores, key=lambda x: x[0])
        else:
            best = min(listOfScores, key=lambda x: x[0])

        if best[0] == 0:
            print("You should mark " + best[1] + " in cell " + best[2] + ".")
            print("This will lead to a tie.")
        elif best[0] > 0:
            print("You should mark " + best[1] + " in cell " + best[2] + ".")
            print("This will lead to a win.")
        else:
            print("You should mark " + best[1] + " in cell " + best[2] + ".")
            print("This will lead to a loss.")

main()
```

Here is the error with traceback:::

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Abby/Desktop/CS 3610/hw2/hw2Copy.py", line 134, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/Abby/Desktop/CS 3610/hw2/hw2Copy.py", line 117, in main
    listOfScores = miniMax(gameBoard)
  File "C:/Users/Abby/Desktop/CS 3610/hw2/hw2Copy.py", line 92, in miniMax
    output = miniMax(xChild) #returns score
  File "C:/Users/Abby/Desktop/CS 3610/hw2/hw2Copy.py", line 81, in miniMax
    if winner(gameBoard) or getEmptySpaces(gameBoard) ==0:
  File "C:/Users/Abby/Desktop/CS 3610/hw2/hw2Copy.py", line 16, in winner
    case1 = gameBoard[0]+gameBoard[1]+gameBoard[2]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

I am entering "----x----" as my input. Please give me some guidance on how to get rid of this error! I know this code is messy, but at the moment I'm okay with that. Thank you!

EDIT::: I got that to work, but now when I try to find my max score, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Abby\Desktop\CS 3610\hw2\hw2Copy.py", line 134, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Abby\Desktop\CS 3610\hw2\hw2Copy.py", line 120, in main
    best = max(listOfScores, key=lambda x: x[0])
TypeError: unorderable types: list() > int()
```

I had previously tested this with my own tuples and it worked, returning a tuple, so I am not sure what is going wrong here. Help please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `markX` function, you should `return gameBoard[:index] + 'x' + gameBoard[index+1:]` Instead of doing `gameBoard = ...`. This will **not** override the variable, as you think it is doing. This is because in python, variables defined in a function is limited to that scope only.

What's happening is `None` is being returned by the function because you never set the function to return anything. Then, you're trying to index `None`, which isn't possible, as `'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`

The same goes for the `markO()` function.

---

For stuff like this, in my opinion, it's better to use a class. That way you are able to deal with one variable, such as `self.gameBoard`, and not have to override it in functions all the time.

Comment: Thank you! I was using a class, but got the same error, so I thought I would try it this way. This should help!

Comment: I made an edit to my original post with a new, exciting error! This is the first time I've tried the max[, key=lambda], etc. so I may be using it incorrectly. Would appreciate any feedback on that.

Comment: @AbigailB You should really ask a separate question for this... but the reason why you're getting an error is because you seem to have nested lists. I don't really know how to fix that because it's your program, so you may have to change to something you're familiar with